# Data clusters using mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, web-applications

I'd want to create multiple database and in each of them maintain a set number of tables (ie 100 database each holding 60 tables). My application will have the infrastructure to know which DB and Table to access to find the data it needs. The content of each table would not exceed beyond 200 records but I want to be able to spread the data across many machines for scalability.

What are the important issues to keep in mind while developing a a distributed system like using mysql? Where can I read to learn more about setting up such a system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great book:

[http://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-MySQL-Optimization-Replication/dp/0596101716/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1294150323&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101716)

Typically you are only as powerful as your weakest database.  If the performance of one slows down, then it will typically lock up web requests.  Make sure to have great monitoring in place for your DB health and for your webapp health

200 records per table (depending on the number of fields and indexes) is a very small table size.  This suggests that you should go back to the drawing board with your design.

100 databases is a lot to keep up with.  If you go this route, automate everything!  That being said, unless you have billions of records, you don't need this.

Based on the information you have provided, I would suggest scrapping your design and looking for something simpler.  If their are external constraints that require this, then hire an operations person with mysql dba skills; what you described is a 10 - 20 hour a week commitment.

Comment: @Aaron, thanks for that response. I was expecting answers suggesting to change the database design. I think one way to do that is to embed more tables per database. The advantage this design is that it can scale horizontally which is important for high traffic apps.

Comment: Given the scale you have suggested in the description their is no reason to think that one database instance can't effectively handle a high traffic app.  Have enough RAM that your indexes are fully loaded into memory and make sure you have proper indexing.

Comment: Later, if you find you are feeling growing pains, first try to add more RAM.  After you have maximized the limits of modern hardware, then start considering more radical database designs.  Sharded databases are a great tool, but should be your last line of defense.

Comment: Thanks again Aaron. I'm not taking a shot at your answer but on Stackoverflow, while valid to some extend, most tend to say "you don't need it". Then what does one have to do to understand the anatomy of distributed database systems? The only way to learn something like this is to try it and learn as you go.

Comment: In that case, I encourage you to build one as an experiment.  It is great to see people curious about this field.  In fact, if I had know that this was a learning exercise as opposed to solving a real world problem, myself and probably the rest of stackoverflow would have been better able to offer guidance.  So, 1) Don't limit yourself to 200 records, have some tables with 100's of million 2) Have unique and non unique key indexes on large tables. 3) load data via many remote clients of both the webserver and background worker variety. 4) look for latency & connection problems & fix them

Answer (score 0):

Based on the number of tables and records I would also recommend to rethink your approach. Designing with horizontal scalability in mind is commendable, but given the data count, you'd probably be better off to have just one DB server, optimised to keep the whole dataset in RAM (plus another node w/ master-slave replication for failover) and you'll be able to keep up with a LOT of traffic.

That aside, based on the little facts I know about your application, I would not recommend splitting your data in that many databases and tables. Sure, you can code whatever logic you want in your application to ensure that it knows where to find stuff but you are going to lose a lot of the power of SQL as you won't be able to combine data from different databases directly using pure SQL.

Comment: sophisticated systems are written in layers. Some of these layers will deal with the database and can execute SQL directly, but on higher layers, direct access to the database is not desirable. This pattern is generally known as Presistance Ignorance and therefore the final point in your answer doesn't really relate to my case.

Comment: I am fully aware of the benefits of layered architectures. But I am also aware that almost all sophisticated (or shall we say "sufficiently complex") systems  will at some point or the other require the developer to "drill holes" into some of these layers, usually in order to get decent performance.

Comment: Sorry, 2nd part of my comment: But that was not my point - I did not recommend to build your application with SQL code spread all over the code. I wanted to say that while your app knows how data is persisted, others don't- and if you come up with other uses of your DB (usually analytics / integration) having a "good" SQL data model pays off.

Comment: Ah, and after reading Aaron's comments above: If this is a learning experiment, then by all means follow Aaron's advice - get (much!) more data, try different ways of loading it, go wild with the MySQL settings etc.   I assumed that you wanted to build a production system - and then, building a horizontally scalable system for the amount of data you mentioned would be a waste of resources (yours and your company's).